# Can't see Default.aspx file in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, default

I've watched a tutorial on youtube about ASP.net. I've created a new ASP.NET Web Application but I can't see the .aspx file anywhere in the solution explorer. So I wonder if I'm blind or I need to additionally create it? This is what my solution explorer looks like:
[image: the solution explorer]

Comment: I've already looked through every drop-down for it.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?  What template did you select to use when creating the new project?

Comment: you may select new empty project ! so right click on LearningASP and select add new item then select webform

Answer (score 0):

You might be confusing between these options. Try experimenting with all these options.

[image]